# How to check if a computer have already joined a domain with Samba

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I am using this command to add a Linux boxes to Active Directory:

```
net ads join -U username%password
```

I have to make this command idempotent by checking the Linux box already exists in the domain. The command line help it is not useful.

I wonder if there is something like:

```
net ads search computer-name
```

I am using Samba 3

Answer (score 3):

Use `net ads testjoin`:

```
# net ads testjoin -k
Join is OK
```

→ This box is joined. Now remove it from the domain and `testjoin` returns -1:

```
 # net ads leave -k
Deleted account for 'DEADBEEF' in realm 'EXAMPLE.COM'
# net ads testjoin -k
Join to domain is not valid: NT code 0xfffffff6
# echo $?
255
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `net ads dn 'queryhere'` to search for a computer object.

For example, I can use the following to find the "Nagios" linux server in the "Servers" OU of my domain:

`net ads dn 'CN=nagios,OU=Servers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com' cn -S DC_NAME -P -l`

The `-P` switch makes it use the computer account to do a lookup (computer must be joined to a domain for this to work) and `-l` gives more verbose information. If it fails, using `-d 10` will show you why.